# mapping multiple functions in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a way of representing memory in Haskell that looks like this...

```
data MemVal = Stored Value | Unbound
          deriving Show

type Memory = ([Ide],Ide -> MemVal)
```

As an Identifier is called its added to the list of Identifiers. If an error occurs in the program I want to be able to recall the identifiers used up to date. So far I have this...

```
display :: Memory -> String
display m = "Memory = " ++ show (map (snd m) (fst m)) ++ " "
```

But was wondering if there were a way to map the name of the identifier to (fst m) as well as the function (snd m) so the output will be similar to...

```
Memory = [sum = stored Numeric 1, x = stored Boolean true]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For example, what is Ide? What is Value?

Comment: How about `show [(ident, snd m ident) | ident <- fst m]`

Comment: Value is
`data Value = Numeric Integer | Boolean Bool | ERROR
            deriving Show`
and Ide is either a Stored Value or Unbound defined by the MemVal

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this

```
display :: Memory -> String
display (ides, mem) = 
   "Memory = [" ++ unwords (map (\x -> x ++ "=" ++ mem x) ides) ++ "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you are after:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

display (Memory ids f) = "Memory = [" ++ (intercalates ", " assigns) ++ "]"
  where assigns = [ show i ++ " = " ++ show (f i) | i <- ids ]
```

Here `assigns` is a list like:

```
[ "sum = stored Numeric 1", "x = stored Boolean true", ...]
```

and `intercalate ", " assigns` joins the strings together.

I've used destructuring to avoid having to refer to `fst ...` and `snd ...`